# jqgrid - items per page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I can't configure items per page for jqgrid. My jqgrid is:

```
        jQuery('#EmployeeTable').jqGrid({
            url: '/Admin/IdeasJSON',
            datatype: 'json',
            postData: { page: page, pageIndex: pageIndex, Filter: Filter, DateStart: DateStart, DateEnd: DateEnd, TagID: TagID, StatusID: StatusID, CategoryID: CategoryID, IsDescription: IsDescription },
            loadComplete: function () { pageIndex = null },
            jsonReader: {
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                root: "rows",
                repeatitems: false,
                id: ""
            },
```

....

and MVC method returns:

```
        var result = new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = new { page = page, total = total, records = totalCount, rows = IdeaForJSONs }
        };
        result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

        return result;
```

where IdeaForJSONs has 50 elements.
I don't know why but grid shows 20 elements. Why?

Comment: The default setting is 20. You have to set it according to your data.

Comment: Right, the `rowNum` option defaults to `20`.

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at the [`rowNum`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) option. From the documentation:

> Sets how many records we want to view in the grid. This parameter is passed to the url for use by the server routine retrieving the data. Note that if you set this parameter to 10 (i.e. retrieve 10 records) and your server return 15 then only 10 records will be loaded.

The default value is 20, which explains why you are only seeing this many rows.

If you increase it to 50 you should see all of your data in the grid:

```
jQuery('#EmployeeTable').jqGrid({
        url: '/Admin/IdeasJSON',
        ...
        rowNum: 50,
```