# jqGrid - Pager not shown. How to enable it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, jqgrid

I dont know why, but im using jqGrid and pager not show properly. I could show the `viewrecords`, but pager not. The rest of the table works ok.

Could anybody give me any idea about where is the problem.

My JQGrid is:

```
jQuery('#report_table').jqGrid({               
     scroll: 'true',               
     url:'getReportTableData.json',                     
     datatype: 'json',             
     height: 400,                   
     width: 800,                    
     colNames:['Futures','Units'],                
     colModel:[
        {name:'Futures',index:'Futures',  width: 150, sortable: false},
        {name:'Units',index:'Units',  width: 150, sortable: false],                
     rowNum:100,                    
     loadonce:'false',               
     shrinkToFit: 'true',              
     mtype: 'POST',                
     pager: '#preport_table',                
     postData: { idReport : '75' }, 
     viewrecords: 'true',            
     loadComplete : function (data) {                        
         if (data.error == 1){                                
             $('#dialog-modal').dialog({                       
                 height: 140, width: 300,  modal: true, title: ' Error ',  
                 buttons: { cerrar : function() { 
                         $(this).dialog('close');                
                     }                                           
                 }                                               
             });                                                 
             $('#dialog-modal').html(msgError(data.msg));    
         }                                                       
     },                                                          
     caption: '',                  
     hidegrid: 'true', 
});
```

And the html code is

```
<table id='report_table'></table> <div id='preport_table' ></div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You main problem is the `scroll: true` option. In [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) of the option you will find the following:

> When enabled, the pager elements are disabled and we can use the
>   vertical scrollbar to load data.

Moreover your code has some syntax errors which you should fix:

- the second column of the `colModel` contain no '}' (see before ']').
- boolean values should be codded as `true` and `false` and not as strings `'true'` and `'false'` (see 
  `scroll: 'true'`, `loadonce:'false'`, `shrinkToFit: 'true'`, `viewrecords: 'true'`, `hidegrid: 'true'`)

Comment: Thank you Oleg. It works. The problem was with 'true' cause the colModel it was ok, but i remove some columns here to make code clear but delete wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For others with my problem, `gridview: true` can cause the pager not to show.  I removed the gridview property and the pager bar appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared some runnable jqGrids to show you how to enable the pager properly (based on the [canonical example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47330980/1016343) I provided in a different answer).

The scroll and gridview properties don't seem to make any difference, I have added those to example 4 below and it still works (it is the only difference compared to grid 3).

**Grid1** displays the data just scrollable, while the second one is displaying a pager.
The difference are the properties:

```
pager: '#pagerGrid2', rowNum: 4, viewrecords: true,
```

where `viewrecords` is just optional to show how many records are available. Omit it to hide the record number display.

The [**`rowNum`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377165/jqgrid-items-per-page) parameter specifies how many rows per page you want to see (here 4). 
Note that because the height (45) is too small here, it still shows a vertical scrollbar - and the pager (1 of 2) at the same time. This is the case in **Grid2**.

To get rid of the scrollbar, increase the size of the height parameter. This is shown in the **Grid3** in the example below.

```js
// see: https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/
// CDN used: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid
$(function() {
  var gridSampleData = [
      { id: 10, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe1"},
      { id: 20, firstName: "Justin", lastName: "Time1" },
      { id: 30, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe2"},
      { id: 40, firstName: "Justin", lastName: "Time2" },
      { id: 11, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe3"},
      { id: 21, firstName: "Justin", lastName: "Time3" },
      { id: 31, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe4"},
      { id: 41, firstName: "Justin", lastName: "Time4" }
    ];
  $("#Grid1").jqGrid({
    height: 45, width: 250,
    colNames: ['First name', 'Last name'],
    colModel: [{name: "firstName"}, {name: "lastName"}],
    data: gridSampleData
  });
  $("#Grid2").jqGrid({
    pager: '#pagerGrid2', rowNum: 4, scroll: false, viewrecords: true,  
    height: 45, width: 400,
    colNames: ['First name', 'Last name'],
    colModel: [{name: "firstName"}, {name: "lastName"}],
    data: gridSampleData
  });
  $("#Grid3").jqGrid({
    pager: '#pagerGrid3', rowNum: 4, scroll: false, viewrecords: true,  
    height: 90, width: 400,
    colNames: ['First name', 'Last name'],
    colModel: [{name: "firstName"}, {name: "lastName"}],
    data: gridSampleData
  });
  $("#Grid4").jqGrid({ scroll: 'true', gridview: true,
    pager: '#pagerGrid4', rowNum: 4, scroll: false, viewrecords: true,  
    height: 90, width: 400,
    colNames: ['First name', 'Last name'],
    colModel: [{name: "firstName"}, {name: "lastName"}],
    data: gridSampleData
  });
});
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<title>Canonical jqGrid example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.2/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.2/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>

<table id="Grid1"></table>
<br/>

<table id="Grid2"></table>
<table id="pagerGrid2"></table>
<br/>

<table id="Grid3"></table>
<table id="pagerGrid3"></table>

<table id="Grid4"></table>
<table id="pagerGrid4"></table>
```

**Note:** Click on **Full page** (upper right corner after you clicked <kbd>Run Code Snippet</kbd> for a better view of the grids).