# Why does jqGrid not show 2nd page when data is loaded dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I have prepared a jsFiddle which simulates to load data into jqGrid from an echo page. This is the example:

**[jqGrid Paging Example (click to run)](https://jsfiddle.net/bny6h1nz/1/)**

```
$(function() {
  var gridSampleData = [
      { id: 10, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe1"},
      { id: 20, firstName: "Justin", lastName: "Time1" },
      { id: 30, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe2"},
      { id: 40, firstName: "Justin", lastName: "Time2" },
      { id: 11, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe3"},
      { id: 21, firstName: "Justin", lastName: "Time3" },
      { id: 31, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe4"},
      { id: 41, firstName: "Justin", lastName: "Time4" }
    ];
  var rowsPerPage = 4;
  var numRows = gridSampleData.length;
  var pagedData = {
    page:1, total:numRows/rowsPerPage, records: numRows, rows: gridSampleData
  }

  // simulate AJAX request: use echoUrl instead of real web service 
  var jsonData = JSON.stringify(pagedData);
  var echoUrl = '/echo/js/?js=' + jsonData; 

  $("#Grid4").jqGrid({ scroll: false, gridview: true,
    pager: '#pagerGrid4', rowNum: rowsPerPage, viewrecords: true,  
    height: 90, width: 400,
    colNames: ['First name', 'Last name'],
    colModel: [{name: "firstName"}, {name: "lastName"}],
    datatype: "json",
        jsonReader: {
      page: "page",
      total: "total",
      records: "records",
      root: "rows",
      repeatitems: false
        },
    mtype: 'POST',
    url: echoUrl
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<title>Canonical jqGrid example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.2/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.2/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>


<table id="Grid4"></table>
<table id="pagerGrid4"></table>
```

Everything looks fine, until you click on the navigation buttons - it will not show you the 2nd page. Why is this? If you load data statically, as grid #4 in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47925880/1016343), it works fine.

**Note:** I had to use jsFiddle, because [StackOverflow currently does not support an echo page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288902/1016343) in the snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in your example you are returning all rows of data but always sending `page: 1`. Each request the grid makes it's told that it is getting data for page 1 it never gets data for page 2. To make your example work you can set the property `loadonce` to true as I have done in a fork of your original code.
 [Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omrhdLs1/)

Or you could rework your code to send the first 4 rows and `page: 1` and when the request comes for page 2 send the last 4 rows and `page: 2`

Answer (score 1):

If you want really simulate loading the data from the server **without** `loadonce: true` then I'd recommend you to use `serializeGridData`, which send `json` parameter (see [the documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#json) of Echo service) with the corresponding page of data. One can use `slice` on the array of source data.

```
serializeGridData: function (request) {
    var start = (request.page - 1) * request.rows;

    return {
        json: JSON.stringify({
            page: request.page,
            total: gridSampleData.length/request.rows,
            records: gridSampleData.length,
            rows: gridSampleData.slice(start, start + request.rows)
        })
    }
}
```

See the corresponding modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/bny6h1nz/2/. One should remark, that the server should typically return *sorted data* based on `sidx` and `sord` parameters (`request.sidx` and `request.sord`). One can implement the feature too using `sort` method of array, which has callback function, but I suppose, you don't want to implement full simulation of server behavior required for jqGrid in JSFiddle.

Comment: That's a really helpful hint, much appreciated Oleg! One question - in my example, I am passing the data via URL parameter, I saw you've configured the echo URL without parameter (url: '/echo/json/'), how does the data "flow" in your example? I am asking because according to the link you provided, the JSON echo is a separate request which requires a data parameter - which I haven't seen in the jqGrid code.

Comment: @Matt: the data from `postData` will be combined with the standard parameters, sent by jqGrid to the server, and will be forwarded to `serializeGridData`, which I used in my demo. Finally the returned value from `serializeGridData` will be used as value of `data` parameter of underlying Ajax request. Thus simple code (for `loadonce: true` scenario) will be `postData: { json: JSON.stringify(gridSampleData) }` or `postData: { json: function () { return JSON.stringify(gridSampleData); } }`. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/bny6h1nz/6/

Comment: Many thanks Oleg - If I could, I would upvote a 2nd time!

Comment: @Matt: You are welcome! I have enough reputation points, which I can't use. Thus voting isn't a problem me (but it could help other people to find the information of stackoverflow). I'm glad, that I could help you.